# Focus on dialog with ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I have some handy mappings set up in my `~/.ideavimrc` some of which result in IntelliJ opening a new window/dialog box. For example the following line lets me type `\t` and it'll open IntelliJ's "jump to test" dialog box which lets me jump to an existing test or create a new test file:

`:map \t :action GotoTest<CR>`

This **almost** works great. The only issue is that when the dialog box pops up the focus is still on the editor window, not the dialog box. As a result I can't simply use the arrow keys to select my option and hit enter. Instead, I have to use the mouse. As a good code nerd, I abhor the mouse. So, how do I get the keyboard focus to change? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed in the master branch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-796, but the fix hasn't been released yet. You can download a CI build and help testing IdeaVim. See https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim for more details.